# Using powershell how to get active features and custom features also in a sharepoint farm

Tags: 2013, powershell, farm-solution, features

How to get all out of the box active features and custom farm solutions features using powershell code in sharepoint 2010 and sharepoint 2013.

Comment: i would give you little advise, as you are regular user of this forum...if, please, you responde the counter questions on your asked questions as well as close if someone solve the issue....really appreciated. we are here only help and in return we need respect in term of vote / marked anser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show all the features on the farm listed by display name and sorted use this:

```
`Get-SPFeature | Sort -Property DisplayName'
```

To see all features for a Web Application:

```
Get-SPFeature -WebApplication http://webapplication
```

To see all features for a Site Collection:

Get-SPFeature -Site http://sitecollection
To see all features for a Site:

```
Get-SPFeature -Web http://siteurl
```

[SharePoint 2010 Powershell Feature Cmdlets](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/09/sharepoint-2010-powershell-feature-cmdlets-2/)

Here is a snippet of Windows PowerShell code to list all the activated Features for a site collection (SPSite):

```
Get-SPSite http://sharepoint2010 | % {

    $results = @()

    Get-SPFeature -Site $_ -Limit All | % {

    $feature = $_; 
        $featuresDefn = (Get-SPFarm).FeatureDefinitions[$_.ID]; 
        $cc = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture;

        $obj = New-Object PSObject;
        $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty  Title  $($featuresDefn.GetTitle($cc));
        $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty  Hidden $($feature.Hidden);

        $results += $obj;
    }
    $results | FT -auto;
}
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/josrod/archive/2013/01/04/powershell-to-list-activated-features-for-a-site-and-web.aspx